# how to get ckeditor iframe object in javascript

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I want to write onkeypress event against ckeditor iframe body. How can I get object of ckeditor object so that I can bind onkeypress event against ckeditor iframe body?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try following code before creating ckeditor instances to bind onkeypress event:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceCreated', function(cke) {
cke.editor.on('contentDom', function() {
   if(cke.editor.name == "YourIntanceName") // YourIntanceName = name of teaxtarea
    {
        cke.editor.document.on('keypress', function(e) {
            var charCode = event.data.getKey();
        });
    }
});
});
```

Comment: To avoid odd issues it's better to use [`editable#attachListener`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editable-method-attachListener) method. See example here http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-contentDom.